# Easy and generic data migration/import with php?

Tags: php, import, data-migration

I am building a php application that work on weather data and agricultural data. I wrote synchronization scrips for all the weather data providers of my users. The users can enter the agricultural data manually. However they usually also enter there agricultural data in other applications (Excel spreadsheet, proprietary applications,...).

I would like to build a tool to help my customers to easily mass import there agricultural data into my system from there other applications. It would be better if this tool can accept custom data format in order to limit the data transformation before the import.

Do you know any php tools/library/classes that could help me to build this without reinventing the wheel?

I know Talend data migration but I would like something completely integrated into my application like a wizard for my users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the exact format of the data your task is impossible. The closest that you can get is if you **build a format specification yourself** or if you build an **API** to your application and allow 3rd party users to insert data according to the specs of your API.

Comment: In fact I would like a library/tool which help me to design an import wizard. The user will be able to import his own custom CSV file and using some mapping mechanism in the UI, the user will be able to map his CSV to my schema.

Comment: This may be doable, but I foresee a complicated future and a lot of issues with this approach, especially if you want to expand your client base. Teaching 1000 people your format is easier than writing code to support 1000 different formats. In the end is a question of how much resources and time do you want to invest in this part of the project and you used the word easy.